# How to generate a gpg4win keypair without passphrase?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I would like to generate a gpg keypair using gpg4win.
I am at the point where a personal OpenPGP key pair is generated, but:

How can I generate a keypair using gpg4win with no passphrase?
The private key should be accessed without passphrase.

Comment: This might be a terrible idea... if anyone ever copied your private key they could then decrypt everything that was ever encrypted to you, without even trying/guessing, even a terrible simple passphrase is better than none. Maybe using a "remember my passphrase all day" option would be better, or using a simple keyfile or passphrase stored in ram could work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help you with the graphical user interface, as I currently do not have a Windows computer around.

But all the graphical user interfaces do is interfacing with the command line `gpg.exe` application (on Linux, OS X and other unixoid systems, you would simply use `gpg` instead), which you can also use directly (and for generating a key, use is definitely not very complicated).

Open a command prompt. If I remember correctly, the GPG4Win installer already sets the PATH variable, so you can directly run `gpg.exe` from any location. If you receive some error message that `gpg.exe` was not found, run `cd C:\Path\To\Your\GnuPG-Folder`, and run the command from there again.

To create a key, use the key generation wizard, which is started by running `gpg.exe --gen-key`. Enter the appropriate details whenever ask, but omit the password (by simply pressing the enter button; be aware no output does show up on the command line if typing passwords!).

The key generated on the command line will also be available in any graphical user interface application.